# Why isn't my code working properly with enviroment variable?

Tags: django, environment-variables

So if-else statement executes like it receives True instead of False, however the print statement displays "False" but god knows why 2 times.

But when I just assign False to DOCKER in settings.py it works as expected.

settings.py:

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta
import environ


env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

environ.Env.read_env()

DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

DOCKER = False # env('DOCKER')

print(DOCKER)
if DOCKER:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'answerly',
            'USER': 'ubuntu',
            'PASSWORD': 'ubuntuanswerly',
            'HOST': 'db',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'answerly',
            'USER': 'ubuntu',
            'PASSWORD': 'ubuntuanswerly',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

.env:

```
DEBUG=on
SECRET_KEY=')fv!ujycyce4rf##exy8q=zbo4)o5dano73-o9(g3ni-41)ed*'
DOCKER=False
```

Comment: DOCKER is a boolean, you should handle it the same as DEBUG. `DOCKER=False` in your .env file assigns the string "False" to DOCKER not the boolean value False

Comment: I know. I tryed to set it in .env as DOCKER=(bool, False) but isn't working either.

Comment: You need to use `DOCKER = env.bool('DOCKER', default=False)` in your settings

Comment: Thanks! It's working.